# Paper physics simulation on a highpoly mesh

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, soft-body

I want to model a highpoly paper cube with a length of 13 cm and a detail of about 16 polygons per cm². As planned, the cube should simply roll due to different external influences (getting minor dents along the way), then a hand grabs it and crushes it, after which the cube should fall to the floor and begin to partially return the shape in accordance with the physics of real paper.

I wanted to recreate the physics of real paper using cloth or soft body modifiers, but in both cases the problem arose already at the stage of animation of a whole calm cube. No matter how high the stiffness and low mass parameters I set, the cube always either crumpled under the influence of gravity, or turned into an incomprehensible polygonal mess, or simply flew out of sight for thousands meters between frames.

Googling gave me advice to reduce the number of polygons. However, this goes against my idea of making a physically correct model that can both maintain its density with smoothness and get realistic wrinkles due to impacts of other objects in the scene without resorting to sculpting.

How can this be implemented in Blender?

Comment: It may be beneficial to add some thickness to your paper by making every quad into a very thin cube.